# Serving Java Applets from a Queue?

Tags: java, applet

I'm looking for a elegant way to create a queue for serving up batch compiled applets.
I have hacked together a SQL and PHP script to handle this but it chokes under mild loads.
is there an existing system that can handle taking a list in SQL and serve the applets in descending order each time it is requested. I'm also trying to handle this all server side as well.

The trick would be getting file001, then file002 ++ ect. to get served each time a web page is loaded. I'm batch creating applets that has a slightly modified background and I'm trying to serve a never been used applet waiting in the queue to load each time the a page is requested.

Is there a applet server I can tweak or does look like something that needs to be built?

Comment: wow.. why..? Why can't you just change the background of a single applet? Are you compiling them on the fly in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

No, I have never heard of a "batch compile applet server".

Could you maybe explain in more detail why you feel this is necessary?

Why don't you just use the same class and pass parameters to it?

That said, you can do compilation on demand quite well with e.g. ant and / or CruiseControl. You could put the pre-compiled applets into a directory. Then your PHP frontend just needs to keep track of what applet it delivered last, and fetch the next one the next time.

Still, this sounds rather complicated to me; so maybe you could explain your motivation.

In particular, why do you want a new applet on every reload? Would that not be rather confusing? Why not offer a link for each variant, so the user can choose?

Comment: I'm working with an embedded platform for kids with a specific kind of developmental disability. I'm trying to get around the limited capability of the hardware I have available. The reason for the loading the applets from a queue is that it takes a little bit of time of generate the pattern. There is a rationale behind this but it would take a few paragraphs to explain the disability. If you see something familiar there is a big disconnect in your brain and it confuses you and totally derails your concentration.

Comment: I'm limited by the hardware with what I can do. I'm trying to handle this server side. I does seem kind of odd, most places just serve a static applet. It's unconventional and I'm using my own system now. I'm just assuming its not the best way to do it even though it works

Comment: I was just interested in finding out if there is something out there that can handle this with some tweaks, scripting, magic or whatever.

Comment: or If it just does this automatically would be great too, I'm just trying to reach out to the vast expanse of the interwebs.

Comment: I understand that you need to generate the pattern on the server for performance reasons. Still, why do you need to recompile the applet? Can't you use one applet that loads the right pattern on demand? In what form do you serve the pattern? As an image, as a generating function?

Comment: As you seem to have rather special needs, I think you will not get a helpful answer unless you explain more about the system, or even make the code accessible somewhere (if you can).